# Batch - Do something if filename contains string

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, batch-rename

I am trying to create a batch file to loop through all files in a directory, converting all files with no extension to a CSV.

I then want it to rename those files as they are given a default filename.
"EDI_ORD_*1*"

To convert the files to CSV I have simply used this:

```
rename *. *.csv
```

Now to loop though all files I am using this:

```
for /r %%i in (*) do (
    echo %%i
)
```

I have tried using find to search each file for "EDI_ORD" but this isn't working. How can I rename only the relevant files? I cannot use the rename command again as I need to change the name based on an account number which is found within each CSV file.

Comment: If you need to read that second information from an additional file you'd have to nest a second look for the contents of that file. Personally I'd rather use PowerShell for this as it supports the command `Import-Csv` among others.

Comment: *I have tried using find to search each file for "EDI_ORD" but this isn't working.* Iterate only files you need. `for /r %%i in (*EDI_ORD*) do`

Comment: Renaming a file to .csv extension doesn't `convert` it in any way. When searching for a file you should filter on it `for /r %%i in (*EDI_ORD*) do (`